# Fetch file content into string from url in Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, file, fetch

I'm getting into vue js right now. Currently I'm trying to get data from an external file (from another server, from url) into a string to parse it into an array. But I'm already failing with the file to string part. I tried using:

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
      lines: [],
      error: '',
      choice: '',
      content: ''
    }
async created() {
    try{
      parseFile();
    }
    catch(err){
      this.error = err.message;
    }
methods: {
    async parseFile() {
      fetch('https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample3.txt')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {console.log(data); this.content = data;});
    }
  }
}
```

Which I want to store into content as a string to split it up later into the lines array.

Sadly it doesn't even load, I will always get nothing in the console. Why might this be? I found in here that you can use raw-loader (or the asset modules now i think) to import a raw file into vue. But it's not my aim to import the raw file into the App.vue to load it. Does anybody have an Idea, why this is not working for me? I'm not so much used to JavaScript, maybe I'm just dumb or so, lol.

Best regards

Comment: as for your problem ... I think you need to use `try{ this.parseFile(); }`

Comment: I using async as I deleted some code for visibility. I was gonna use await for the parsing, so the file content is in the string already before I'm starting to parse it into the array.

Comment: fair enough, comment removed, other comment probably shows the issue

Comment: Forgot to type the 'this'. Thanks man, I feel pretty dumb right now.

Now I'm still getting an error

Access to fetch at 'https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample3.txt' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://filesamples.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I think I might be able to google that.

Comment: yeah, that's a [CORS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNtFSVU-YTI) issue - only *fixable* on the server

Comment: Ok that helps me a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, you are using a promise chain to get the result of the fetch, but you're getting a CORS error on the request which isn't captured.

I have changed the format of the code and added an extra try catch you will see 'error in fetch' logged to the console.

```
async parseFile() {
   try {
     const fetchResponse = await fetch(
       "https://filesamples.com/samples/document/txt/sample3.txt"
     );
     console.log(fetchResponse.text());
   } catch (ex) {
     console.log("Error in fetch");
   }
}
```

https://codepen.io/DanielRivers/pen/qBVpZOo

Comment: Thanks man! I'm currently reading this:
https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin

Do you maybe also know how I can change the origin in the cors header for my fetch request?

Comment: This is something that can only be changed on the server, if your end goal is to get local files on your own domain then it will not be a problem when you progress.  

Clearly this filesamples.com site does not want their files used in this way.

Comment: `There is nothing wrong with your code` really? it should be `this.parseFile()`

Comment: I missed that in my write up, but I did supply a working codepen.  The code shared and more than just `this.` missing it was clear he butchered it to paste here

Comment: @Daniel Rivers end goal are files from another resource, which seems to work fine! Thanks man!